# Replacing log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar,log4j-core-2.0-beta9 with log4j-api-2.0.1.jar and log4j-core-2.0.1.jar not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, log4jdbc

I am trying to use the new log4j2 release in my application and it is not working. It was working when i used log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar and log4j-core-2.0-beta9 but its not working after i replaced it with the new release:  log4j-api-2.0.1.jar and log4j-core-2.0.1.jar

My application is developed using spring MVC and struts 2. 
Is there any extra reconfiguration that needed before running?

Comment: But what errors do you get? Do you have some sort of stack trace? Where do you use that? It is impossible to answer your questions without knowing more details!

Comment: The problem is that its not logging at all. I can't see the exception.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to say what the problem is without seeing your configurations.  (According to the release notes, there were a number of bug fixes for configuration related issues ...)

However, you may be able to work out the cause of your problem for yourself by enabling "status" logging, and looking at what happens during configuration.

Reference:

- [Configuring Log4j 2: Status Messages](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom log4j2 plugin you need to build that jar again with the new log4j2 jars.